# WebGL draw triangles to screen one point at a time

Tags: javascript, graphics, 2d, webgl

I am really new to WebGL and have been trying to create a program that will draw points of a color specified in color sliders on the canvas with a mouse click and after three points are drawn, they will be connected into a triangle. I created an array called "points" to pass in the data of the mouse position on click and then I flatten that into "vertexData" to be sent to the buffer and shaders. I cant get anything to come up currently however. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

"use strict";

```
// Constructor
//
// @param canvasID - string containing name of canvas to render.
//          Buttons and sliders should be prefixed with this string.
//
function Lab2(canvasID /* name of canvas to render */) {
  this.canvasID = canvasID;
  this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID);
  if (!this.canvas) {
    alert("Canvas ID '" + canvasID + "' not found.");
    return;
  }
  this.gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(this.canvas);
  if (!this.gl) {
    alert("WebGL isn't available in this browser");
    return;
  }

  this.init();
}

// Define prototype values common to all Lab2 objects
Lab2.prototype.gl = null;

Lab2.prototype.toString = function () {
  return JSON.stringify(this);
};

Lab2.prototype.init = function () {
  var canvas = this.canvas;
  var gl = this.gl;
  var t = this;  // make available to event handlers

  // WebGL setup
  gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Compile and link shaders
  this.shaderProgram = initShaders(gl, "vShader.glsl", "fShader.glsl");
  if (this.shaderProgram === null)
    return;
  gl.useProgram(this.shaderProgram);

  // Define names for colors
  var white = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  var red = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  var green = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  var blue = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  var yellow = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  // Array of alternating initial vertex coordinates and colors for each vertex
  var points = [];

  this.vertexData = flatten(points);

  // Count of points in vertexData
  this.pointCount = points.size();

  var floatSize = 4;  // size of gl.FLOAT in bytes
  // Load vertex data into WebGL buffer
  this.vertexCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();  // get unique buffer ID
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexCoordBuffer);  // make this the active buffer
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexData, gl.STATIC_DRAW);  // write data to buffer

  // Define data layout in buffer for position.  Postions are 3 floats,
  // interleaved with 3 floats for colors, starting at beginning of buffer.
  this.vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(this.shaderProgram, "vPosition");
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.vPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 6 * floatSize, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.vPosition);

  // Define data layout in buffer for colors.  Colors are 3 floats,
  // interleaved with 3 floats for positions, starting after first position in buffer.
  this.vColor = gl.getAttribLocation(this.shaderProgram, "vColor");
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.vColor, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 6 * floatSize, 3 * floatSize);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.vColor);

  // Define callback for change of slider value
  var sliderCallback = function (e) {
    // Update text display for slider
    var color = e.target.value;
    e.target.valueDisplay.textContent = color;

    // Re-render canvas
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  };

  // Set up HTML user interface
  this.colors = ["r", "g", "b"];
  var rgbSliders = [];         // array of slider HTML elements
  var rgbSliderValues = [];    // array of slider value HTML elements

  // Set up an object with sliders for the three colors. The sliders are
  // accessed using "indices" of "r", "g", and "b".
  for (var i in this.colors) {
    var color = this.colors[i];
    var sliderID = this.canvasID + "-" + color + "-slider";
    rgbSliders[color] = document.getElementById(sliderID);
    if (rgbSliders[color] === null) {
      alert("Slider ID not found: " + sliderID);
      return;
    }
    var valueID = this.canvasID + "-" + color + "-value";
    rgbSliderValues[color] = document.getElementById(valueID);
    if (rgbSliders[color] === null) {
      alert("Slider value ID not found: " + sliderID);
      return;
    }
    rgbSliders[color].valueDisplay = rgbSliderValues[color];  // attach to slider

    // Set callback on slider input
    rgbSliders[color].addEventListener("input", sliderCallback);
  }
  this.rgbSliders = rgbSliders;

  var resetButton = document.getElementById(this.canvasID + "-reset-button");
  if (resetButton === null) {
    alert("Reset button ID not found: " + this.canvasID + "-reset-button");
    return;
  }

  // Set up callback to render a frame
  var render = function () {
    t.Render();
  };

  // Set up the callback for the reset button
  resetButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    // Reset all the sliders to the middle value
    for (var i in rgbSliders) {
      rgbSliders[i].value = rgbSliders[i].max / 2.0;
      rgbSliders[i].valueDisplay.textContent =
              rgbSliders[i].valueAsNumber / rgbSliders[i].max;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  });

  // Set up mouse tracking
  var mouseX = document.getElementById(this.canvasID + "-mousex");
  var mouseY = document.getElementById(this.canvasID + "-mousey");
  var mouseButton = document.getElementById(this.canvasID + "-mousebutton");
  this.mouseDown = [ false, false, false ];  // track mouse button state
  mouseButton.textContent = this.mouseDown;
  if (mouseX === null || mouseY === null || mouseButton === null) {
    alert("Mouse output HTML IDs not found");
    return;
  }

  // Add mouse event handlers
  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
    t.mouseDown[e.button] = true;
    mouseButton.textContent = t.mouseDown;
    getMouseClickPosition();
  });
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
    t.mouseDown[e.button] = false;
    mouseButton.textContent = t.mouseDown;
  });
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    mouseX.textContent = e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft;
    mouseY.textContent = e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop;
  });

  // Kick things off with an initial rendering
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
};

/**
 * GetSliderColors - get the current RGB color represented by the sliders
 *   as a vec3.
 *   
 * @returns {vec3} current slider color
 */
Lab2.prototype.getSliderColor = function () {
  // Build an array of color values based on the current slider colors
  var colorValues = [];
  for (var i in this.colors) {
    var color = this.colors[i];
    var colorValue = this.rgbSliders[color].valueAsNumber;
    colorValues[i] = colorValue;
  }

  return vec3(colorValues);
};

Lab2.prototype.getMouseClickPosition = function (){
    var point = vec2(this.mouseX, this.mouseY);
    this.points.push(point);
};

/**
 * Render - draw the frame
 *
 */
Lab2.prototype.Render = function () {
  var gl = this.gl;
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 1.0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, this.pointCount);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with the code above

As a start you create an empty array called `points` and then flatten it, it's empty so the flattened version is empty, you then make a WebGL buffer that's empty as a result. Pushing points into the javascript array won't update the buffer in WebGL so at a minimum you need to update the buffer in WebGL each time you add points.

```
Lab2.prototype.getMouseClickPosition = function (){
    var point = vec2(this.mouseX, this.mouseY);
    this.points.push(point);

    this.vertexData = flatten(this.points);

    // Count of points in vertexData
    this.pointCount = this.points.size();

    var floatSize = 4;  // size of gl.FLOAT in bytes
    // Load vertex data into WebGL buffer
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexCoordBuffer);  // make this the active buffer
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexData, gl.STATIC_DRAW);  // write data to buffer
```

Further you add 2d values to `points` in `getMouseClickPosition` but according to your code where you create the WebGL buffers you've set it up so it expects points with 3 values each, not 2, and then expects 3 color values. In other words you're putting `[x, y, x, y, x, y]` in `points` but based on your setup code it needs to be `[x, y, z, r, g, b, x, y, z, r, g, b, x, y, z, r, g, b]`

```
Lab2.prototype.getMouseClickPosition = function (){
    var point = vec3(this.mouseX, this.mouseY, 0);  // no idea what Z value you want
    this.points.push(point);
    this.points.push(vec3(red, green, blue));   // you need to figure out red, green, and blue
     ...
```

further you're calling `points` is a javascript array so this code

```
this.pointCount = points.size();
```

makes no sense and would likely crash since there is no `size` function for javascript arrays. The length of an array is `array.length` as in `points.length` and further, if you're putting 2 vec3 values per point, one for position, one for color, then the pointCount is `points.length / 2`

I also see no where where `this.points` is assigned even though it's referenced.

And that's just some of the issues.

- If you want to draw both points and triangles you'll need 2 calls to `gl.drawArrays`. One for points and one for triangles.
- `this.mouseX` and `this.mouseY` are not defined.
- getSliderColor returns an array of vec3 instead of vec3
- not calling render after adding a point
- other...

And you didn't show your shaders. It *seems* unlikely the code would work as is as you're passing in pixel coordinates but shaders work with clip space coordinates. There is no setup in your code to deal with that conversion. It's possible it's hard coded in your shaders but that's not normal. It's more common to pass in the canvas resolution in one form or another, a projection matrix, or to convert to clip space in JavaScript (less common) but nothing like any one of those appears in your code.

I'd suggest you learn how to [use a debugger](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript) as it would show errors for some of the issues with the code.

I'd also suggest [these articles](https://webglfundamentals.org/) for more WebGL help.

```js
// Constructor
//
// @param canvasID - string containing name of canvas to render.
//          Buttons and sliders should be prefixed with this string.
//
function Lab2(canvasID /* name of canvas to render */) {
  this.canvasID = canvasID;
  this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID);
  if (!this.canvas) {
    alert("Canvas ID '" + canvasID + "' not found.");
    return;
  }
  this.gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(this.canvas);
  if (!this.gl) {
    alert("WebGL isn't available in this browser");
    return;
  }

  this.init();
}

// Define prototype values common to all Lab2 objects
Lab2.prototype.gl = null;

Lab2.prototype.toString = function () {
  return JSON.stringify(this);
};

Lab2.prototype.init = function () {
  var canvas = this.canvas;
  var gl = this.gl;
  var t = this;  // make available to event handlers

  // WebGL setup
  gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Compile and link shaders
  this.shaderProgram = initShaders(gl, "vShader.glsl", "fShader.glsl");
  if (this.shaderProgram === null)
    return;
  gl.useProgram(this.shaderProgram);
  this.resolutionLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(this.shaderProgram, 'resolution');

  // Define names for colors
  var white = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  var red = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  var green = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  var blue = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  var yellow = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  // Array of alternating initial vertex coordinates and colors for each vertex
  var points = [];

  this.points = points;
  this.vertexData = flatten(points);

  // Count of points in vertexData
  this.pointCount = 0;

  var floatSize = 4;  // size of gl.FLOAT in bytes
  // Load vertex data into WebGL buffer
  this.vertexCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();  // get unique buffer ID
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexCoordBuffer);  // make this the active buffer
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexData, gl.STATIC_DRAW);  // write data to buffer

  // Define data layout in buffer for position.  Postions are 3 floats,
  // interleaved with 3 floats for colors, starting at beginning of buffer.
  this.vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(this.shaderProgram, "vPosition");
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.vPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 6 * floatSize, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.vPosition);

  // Define data layout in buffer for colors.  Colors are 3 floats,
  // interleaved with 3 floats for positions, starting after first position in buffer.
  this.vColor = gl.getAttribLocation(this.shaderProgram, "vColor");
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.vColor, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 6 * floatSize, 3 * floatSize);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.vColor);

  // Define callback for change of slider value
  var sliderCallback = function (e) {
    // Update text display for slider
    var color = e.target.value;
    e.target.valueDisplay.textContent = color;

    // Re-render canvas
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  };

  // Set up HTML user interface
  this.colors = ["r", "g", "b"];
  var rgbSliders = [];         // array of slider HTML elements
  var rgbSliderValues = [];    // array of slider value HTML elements

  // Set up an object with sliders for the three colors. The sliders are
  // accessed using "indices" of "r", "g", and "b".
  for (var i in this.colors) {
    var color = this.colors[i];
    var sliderID = this.canvasID + "-" + color + "-slider";
    rgbSliders[color] = document.getElementById(sliderID);
    if (rgbSliders[color] === null) {
      alert("Slider ID not found: " + sliderID);
      return;
    }
    var valueID = this.canvasID + "-" + color + "-value";
    rgbSliderValues[color] = document.getElementById(valueID);
    if (rgbSliders[color] === null) {
      alert("Slider value ID not found: " + sliderID);
      return;
    }
    rgbSliders[color].valueDisplay = rgbSliderValues[color];  // attach to slider

    // Set callback on slider input
    rgbSliders[color].addEventListener("input", sliderCallback);
  }
  this.rgbSliders = rgbSliders;

  var resetButton = document.getElementById(this.canvasID + "-reset-button");
  if (resetButton === null) {
    alert("Reset button ID not found: " + this.canvasID + "-reset-button");
    return;
  }

  // Set up callback to render a frame
  var render = function () {
    t.Render();
  };

  // Set up the callback for the reset button
  resetButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    // Reset all the sliders to the middle value
    for (var i in rgbSliders) {
      rgbSliders[i].value = rgbSliders[i].max / 2.0;
      rgbSliders[i].valueDisplay.textContent =
              rgbSliders[i].valueAsNumber / rgbSliders[i].max;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  });

  // Set up mouse tracking
  var mouseX = document.getElementById(this.canvasID + "-mousex");
  var mouseY = document.getElementById(this.canvasID + "-mousey");
  var mouseButton = document.getElementById(this.canvasID + "-mousebutton");
  this.mouseDown = [ false, false, false ];  // track mouse button state
  mouseButton.textContent = this.mouseDown;
  if (mouseX === null || mouseY === null || mouseButton === null) {
    alert("Mouse output HTML IDs not found");
    return;
  }

  // Add mouse event handlers
  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
    t.mouseDown[e.button] = true;
    mouseButton.textContent = t.mouseDown;
    t.mouseX = e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft;
    t.mouseY = e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop;
    t.getMouseClickPosition();
    requestAnimationFrame(render);    
  });
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
    t.mouseDown[e.button] = false;
    mouseButton.textContent = t.mouseDown;
  });
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    mouseX.textContent = e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft;
    mouseY.textContent = e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop;
  });

  // Kick things off with an initial rendering
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
};

/**
 * GetSliderColors - get the current RGB color represented by the sliders
 *   as a vec3.
 *   
 * @returns {vec3} current slider color
 */
Lab2.prototype.getSliderColor = function () {
  // Build an array of color values based on the current slider colors
  var colorValues = [];
  for (var i in this.colors) {
    var color = this.colors[i];
    var colorValue = this.rgbSliders[color].valueAsNumber;
    colorValues[i] = colorValue;
  }

  return vec3(...colorValues);
};

Lab2.prototype.getMouseClickPosition = function (){
    var point = vec3(this.mouseX, this.mouseY, 0);
    this.points.push(point, this.getSliderColor());
    
  this.vertexData = flatten(this.points);

  // Count of points in vertexData
  this.pointCount = this.points.length / 2;

  var floatSize = 4;  // size of gl.FLOAT in bytes
  var gl = this.gl;
  // Load vertex data into WebGL buffer
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexCoordBuffer);  // make this the active buffer
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexData, gl.STATIC_DRAW);  // write data to buffer
    
};

/**
 * Render - draw the frame
 *
 */
Lab2.prototype.Render = function () {
  var gl = this.gl;
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 1.0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  if (!this.pointCount) return;
  gl.useProgram(this.shaderProgram);
  gl.uniform2f(this.resolutionLoc, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, this.pointCount);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, this.pointCount);
};

const WebGLUtils = {
  setupWebGL(elem) { return elem.getContext('webgl'); },
};
function initShaders(gl, vsHref, fsHref) {
  // ignore vsHref and fsHref and guess what the shaders are
  return twgl.createProgram(gl, [`
    attribute vec4 vPosition;
    attribute vec3 vColor;
    uniform vec2 resolution;
    varying vec3 v_color;
    void main() {
      gl_PointSize = 10.0;
      gl_Position = vec4(vPosition.xy / resolution * vec2(2, -2) + vec2(-1, 1), 0, 1);
      v_color = vColor;
    }
  `, `
     precision mediump float;
     varying vec3 v_color;
     void main() {
       gl_FragColor = vec4(v_color, 1);
     }
  `]);
}
const vec3 = (x, y, z) => [x, y, z];
const flatten = a => new Float32Array(a.flat());
const lab = new Lab2('c');
```

```css
#outer { display: flex; }
```

```html
<div id="outer"><canvas id='c'></canvas><div>
<input type="range" value="1" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" id="c-r-slider"><span id="c-r-value"></span><br>
<input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01"  id="c-g-slider"><span id="c-g-value"></span><br>
<input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01"  id="c-b-slider"><span id="c-b-value"></span><br>
<button type="button" id="c-reset-button">reset</button>
<div id="c-mousex"></div>
<div id="c-mousey"></div>
<div id="c-mousebutton"></div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I figured that there would be a lot of issues since I am new to this but this is really helpful so thank you!